# Fastest implementation of a method that transforms boolean arrays to integers in java

Tags: java, bit-shift

Is there a way that this method can be improved in terms of speed?:

```
static int booleanArrayToInt(boolean[] array) {
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (boolean b : array) {
        i++;
        if (b) {
            x = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j]) x = (x << 1) + 1;
        else x = x << 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: So do you want `[ true, true, false]` to look like `[1, 1, 0]`  or `110` or `6`?

Comment: It should return 6.

Comment: By the way, depending on the situation, you can often avoid conversions to and from boolean arrays by doing everything with the "packed" representation instead. For example iterating over all possible subsets is easier *without* using boolean arrays..

Comment: @harold yeah true, I already had that code for another reason and was just including it here so that people could have a valid way to performance test methods for the question at hand. Good point though.

Comment: You're microoptimizing something that's going to be massively swamped by everything else involved here.

Comment: The fact that a string version is listed here is enough for me to be morally confident.

Comment: I listed that version because I was comparing one of the submitted answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```java
      boolean[] bools =
            { true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true
            };
        public static int binaryToInt(boolean[] bools) {
          int x = 0;
          for (boolean b : bools) {
             x <<= 1;
             x |= b ? 1
               : 0;
          }
          return x;
        }
```

Comment: This isn't any faster than `if (b) { x++; }` and isn't quite as clear.